# Opsworks - Recipe Compile Error Wordpress - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks, cookbook

Trying to execute recipes on an Opsworks setup. All apps are Wordpress sites and they deploy fine but when trying to execute recipes via chef i get the following error log.

I've just created this app from scratch so it's brand new. I believe if i create this on another stack it may work fine. Could it be possible i've not setup the database or something like that correctly?

This error is sometimes a regular occurrence and i believe it may be related to a previous Opsworks app not being deployed correctly, stuck on how to fix this as the logs don't really provide much info for me.

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/wordpress/recipes/configure.rb
================================================================================


NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/wordpress/recipes/configure.rb:50:in `block in from_file'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/wordpress/recipes/configure.rb:26:in `each'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/wordpress/recipes/configure.rb:26:in `from_file'


Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/wordpress/recipes/configure.rb:

43:              :host       => (deploy[:database][:host] rescue nil),
44:              :keys       => (keys rescue nil)
45:          )
46:      end
47:  
48:  
49:    # Import Wordpress database backup from file if it exists
50>>     mysql_command = "/usr/bin/mysql -h #{deploy[:database][:host]} -u #{deploy[:database][:username]} #{node[:mysql][:server_root_password].blank? ? '' : "-p#{node[:mysql][:server_root_password]}"} #{deploy[:database][:database]}"
51:  
52:    Chef::Log.debug("Importing Wordpress database backup...")
53:    script "memory_swap" do
54:        interpreter "bash"
55:        user "root"
56:        cwd "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current/"
57:        code <<-EOH
58:            if ls #{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current/*.sql &> /dev/null; then 
59:                #{mysql_command} < #{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current/*.sql;



[2016-09-21T23:42:52+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2016-09-21T23:42:52+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2016-09-21T23:42:52+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-09-21T23:42:52+00:00] ERROR: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
[2016-09-21T23:42:52+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: Can you link to which `wordpress` cookbook you are using? Did you write it yourself?

Comment: https://github.com/joshuakelly/cookbooks

Comment: We have no clue of what is in the node attribute under deploy key. So hard to tell what's going wrong there. There's no values in the attribute file. So probably something done wrong in opsworks...

Comment: Which chef version do you have in the new stack? for Chef v12 I had to use a search method to find the deployed app and its attributes

Comment: I bet that you just don't have attributes in node[:mysql]